# Linq To Sql - Reading DB with old schema

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a DB (SQL CE 3.5) and i am using code first to write into a database (say version-1).
  Over time one of the table (SAY TABLE1) signature has changed (one new attribute added- say ATTRIB1), now when i try to read the old database using the new table signature (schema in code), the code understandably throws an exception complaining about the new ATTRIB1 (which is present in code but not in DB).

```
List<TABLE1> list= this.dataContext.TABLE1.ToList(); --> throws exception
```

- Is there any way i can ignore columns that dont exist in linq to sql.
- Read the DB table into an "entity" and query the value of the columns i need explicitly.
- Any ideas about how best to handle DB versioning.

thanks

Comment: Google for "code first migrations"

Answer (score 0):

Code First Migrations surely would have been a complete approach.
I was looking for something cheap and cheerful :), did that by basically saving an upgrade script for each increment of the database version.
So while reading an old schema, i first upgraded it to the current version by applying the upgrade scripts progressively (this was something my project could live with).